# How does boss difficulty scale when the player is on the verge of upgrading the potion?

Tags: diablo-iv

I am at lvl 44, about to face the final boss. The next potion upgrade is at lvl 45, healing almost twice the previous potion.

How does the ratio of healing:difficulty scale in this scenario? Will it be "easier" to level up to 45 since the potion will "drastically" improve, or will the jump to 45 also "drastically" boost the boss difficulty accordingly?

Comment: This is my opinion so not an actual answer. But one level probably wont' make or break the difficulty. But that upgraded potion definitely can make some difference if you feel like it's been an issue beforehand. 
If you still have renown left to get, clearing out a few dungeons to get that level and the possibility for some new loot as well. That can be a worthwhile investment.

Comment: I did notice an effect going from 59 to 60 of this nature, but I am unsure of the actual ratio.

Answer (score 2):

If the amount of healing a potion charge gives you is the limiting factor, then you're probably better off leveling up to 45 and upgrading your potion.
The effectiveness of the potion increases by a relatively big step, the previous step was at 30 and the next will be at level 60, while the boss will only go up 1 level.

If you run out of potion charges or get oneshot by the boss the bigger potion isn't going to help you win the fight.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, the problem in the game is that these "gatekeeping bosses" tend to one shot you, where nothing else does this so consistently at whatever level you are at. The potion isn't  going to help either way in that case.

Socketing gems with +life% will be more impactful: you will survive those cheap shots so that the potion can then be used. You can swap out the gems for something else afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry too much about the potion, instead go and try to defeat the boss. If it doesn't work and you feel like you almost won - try again. If that doesn't work - level up a bit, get better gear and upgrade your potion.

A lot more depends on the gear, skills and play style rather than potion, so don't get too focused on it. Maybe do a few dungeons/side quests to get the renown, it will grant you with extra experience, possibly a (few) skill points and extra potions you can carry.

And don't forget that all potions heal you for 35% of your total life over 3 seconds, it's only the initial instant heal that differs.

Of course if you are playing hardcore, then certainly level up before trying the fight